# Cover flow model screen adjust in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Below is the link for making the cover flow model in iphone. This is a sample tutorial.

http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m

Can any one tell me how can i make the cover flow model to adjust some where up on the screen. Currently it is in the centre of the screen i want if about 70 to 80pixels to move up in the screen.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlowcoverView is just a subclass of UIView so you can put it anywhere you want within another view in Interface Builder. Then setup an IBOutlet in your view controller so you can interact with it.